Is there any way to unlock my Private Safe on my Oneplus device via the use of adb?
I'm using Private Safe on my Oneplus device. I need to unlock my private safe as I have forgotten both the password and the privacy question that I had previously set.
I have already tried out
adb shell
settings put secure privacy_password_is_open 0
settings put secure access_control_lock_enabled 0
reboot

These commands were the best bet I could find and they don't work.
I don't know any other commands since I'm quite new to this. Any help is appreciated.
